# is it correct to say "this happens in 2014 Norway"?

Tags: expressions

Is it correct to say "this happens in 2014 Norway"? or how to say it correctly? Thanks

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. What meaning are you trying to convey?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That phrase is not correct. I'll take a guess at what you're trying to say and the right way to say it.

If you're talking about a particular event that happened in Norway in 2014, you could say "This happened in Norway in 2014." Note *happened* with an *ed* because it's past tense, and two uses of "in." If you wanted to emphasize the year 2014, you could say "This happened in 2014 in Norway."

If the event occurred not just once but regularly over time, you could say, "this used to happen" but it would sound odd to say that something "used to happen in 2014."

Comment: Hello, Adam. The historic / dramatic present is grammatically totally acceptable. If OP is asking a question at a much more basic level, ELU is not the place to ask it.